# Como passar 2 valores do meu dropdown

Tags: c#, razor

Estou tentando enviar 2 valores retornados do meu dropdown pra minha action, porém não estou encontrando uma solução.

Meu dropdown lista os resultados de uma consulta no banco e retorna 2 valores por item, eu quero enviar ambos para minha action

```
[HttpPost]
public List<ApiLServico.NivelGrupoObject> Form_Load()
{

    int idGp = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IdGrupoAgente"]);
    var retorno = api.ListarNiveis(idGp);
    List<ApiLServico.NivelGrupoObject> agrupamentos = new List<ApiLServico.NivelGrupoObject>();

    for (var i = 0; i < retorno.Length; i++)
    {
        ApiLServico.NivelGrupoObject nivel = new ApiLServico.NivelGrupoObject()
        {
            Id = retorno[i].Id,
            Nome = retorno[i].Nome
        };

        agrupamentos.Add(nivel);
    }
    return agrupamentos;
}
```

Minha action recebe o formulário completo

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(ApiLServico.ContatoObject _user,
string cpf, string _ddd, string _telefone, int _agrupamentoId, string _agrupamentoNome)
    {}
```

```
 <form method="POST" style="max-width:700px; margin:auto;">

    .... (outros campos)

    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        @Html.DropDownList("Niveis")
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:128px">Cadastrar</button>
 </div>
```

Os valores que quero enviar são `agrupamentoId = Id do dropdown` e `agrupamentoNome = Nome do dropdown`

Como faço para enviar ambos os valores pro meu formulário?

Comment: Como é feito o `Post` do `form`?

Comment: ```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(ApiLServico.ContatoObject _user,
string cpf, string _ddd, string _telefone, int _agrupamentoId, string _agrupamentoNome)
{}```

este é o submit do formulário

Comment: por favor, para adicionar itens adicionais no post basta usar a opção [edit]. Me refiro na parte da View, como é realizado o envio dos dados.

Comment: Desculpe não tinha entendido, é um POST comum usando a tag `method`, os inputs são controlados pelo `name`, atualizei com a montagem do form

Comment: hum.. eu não conheço uma forma simples de fazer isso(só com "gambiarra"), porém dados do lado do cliente podem não ser "confiáveis", não compensa mais enviar o ID e na sua Action buscar os dados no banco?